# SQL WHERE doesn't work with CakePHP 2

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

This a following of my previous question but the problem changed so I ask a new one.

I have a table named **Sales** and 3 rows named *Seller*, *Buyer* and *Price*.

In a HTML page, I display the result of this query in a HTML table in myview.ctp :

```
public function myview() {
    $this->set('mysales', $this-Sales>find('all', 
    array('sum(price)AS total','group' => array('seller_name','buyer_name'))));
}
```

In each line where the result is displayed, there's a link which send the seller name and the buyer name of the line clicked and will help creating a PDF with the sale details :

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("PDF", array(
    "controller" => "name of controller",
    "action"     => "myview_pdf",
    "?" => array(
       "seller_name0" => $thesales['Sales']['seller_name'],
       "buyer_name0" => $thesales['Sales']['buyer_name']
    )
 )); ?>
```

I got this function in the controller which receives the seller and buyer names of the line clicked :

```
public function myview_pdf(){

    $this->set('seller_name1', $this->request->query("seller_name0"));
    $this->set('buyer_name1', $this->request->query("buyer_name0")); 
}
```

Now I want to do this SQL query :

```
SELECT detail1_of_sale, detail2_of_sale, detail3_of_sale, detail4_of_sale
FROM sales
WHERE seller_name = 'seller_name1', buyer_name = 'buyer_name1'
```

Which I hope will help me display the details of the sale involving seller_name1 and buyer_name1

What I tried to do is this (in the controller, function myview_pdf) :

```
$this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all',
            array(
                'fields' => array('detail1_of_sale','detail2_of_sale','detail3_of_sale','detail4_of_sale'),
                'conditions' => array('seller_name' => $seller_name1, 'buyer_name' => $buyer_name1)
            )
        ));
```

I don't know if it's a syntax mistake or what it just tells me that $seller_name1 and $buyer_name1 are undefined variables.

**Note :** When I take off the conditions, the $seller_name1 and $buyer_name1 are displayed correctly with a simple echo.

*Huge thanks to Object Manipulator for helping me so far*

Comment: You need an AND (or OR) between the conditions.

Comment: _'conditions' => array(
                    'seller_name' => $seller_name1, 
                    'AND' => array(
                        array(
                            'buyer_name' => $buyer_name1)))_ Is it correct ? Because it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that $seller_name1 and $buyer_name1 is echoed correctly. because you use $this->set which can be accessed by view class. Try to use separate variable for this two. like $seller_name1 = $this->request->

Comment: @Pavel This is what I wrote in **Note** at the end : when I take off the conditions, the seller_name1 and buyer_name1 are echoed correctly

Comment: where exactly are you echoing the two variables? Perhaps in the view? Because when you set their value in the controller using `set` you are passing them to the view but they are not accessible inside the controller.

Comment: @arilia Yes I echoed them in myview_pdf.ctp. Hmm ok I see so I did this instead : http://hpics.li/96884ab
But the conditions **buyer_name** doesn't work and I can't display the variable **buyer_name**.
The display of **seller_name** and the conditions of **seller_name** work fine.